Error with connection to database while using docker (golang)
I have one problem with docker
func ConnectToDB() {
    var err error
    dsn := "host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres dbname=yandex port=5432 sslmode=disable"
    DB, err = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to connect with database")
    }
}

that's my function that connect's to db
and that's my docker-compose file
version: "3.8"
services:
  server:
    container_name: server
    build:
      context: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./static
        target: /app/static
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
  postgres:
    container_name: storage
    image: postgres:16.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: yandex
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./init.sql
        target: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

So after commands
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
that gives me an error
server   | [error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to host=localhost user=postgres database=yandex: dial error (dial tcp [::1]:5432: connect: cannot assign requested address)
server   | 2024/05/02 20:17:58 failed to connect with database
can you tell what am I doing wrong?
I tried to change localhost in function
like thist
func ConnectToDB() {
    var err error
    dsn := "host=postgres user=postgres password=postgres dbname=yandex port=5432 sslmode=disable"
    DB, err = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to connect with database")
    }
}

and that worked
but why?

Assuming that go code is running inside your server container:

Uses 'localhost' doesn't work because within the server container there is no database running on localhost (it's running on your host, not within that container)

Changing 'localhost' to 'postgres' works because docker is managing dns within your server container and defining a route to the database using the name you gave it within your docker-compose definition (postgres).


Does that make sense?
